# PayPal OpenId Connect with MVC

Tags: paypal, openid, dotnetopenauth

Has anyone had luck getting Login With PayPal to work with MVC4?  I've tried creating an extension of OAuth2Client, as well as a separate extension of OpenIdClient.  Both had the same problem, which was also the problem that occurs directly from a browser.

I copy/paste the endpoint URL (with querystring) into the browser, but it always goes directly to the callback URL without displaying any PayPal-hosted login form.  I can verify that the endpoint is correct by removing or altering the redirect_uri (which results in a PayPal error page.)

I am logged out of PayPal through the browser before attempting the tests, and I've tested with Chrome and IE9.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, PayPal OpenId Connect does not support the "openid" scope.  This was verified for my application by using the Login With PayPal button creator and seeing "invalid scope" appended to the redirect's querystring.

The solution (remove "openid" from the scope) presents its own conundrum.  According to the spec for OpenId, this scope is REQUIRED.  According to the documentation for PayPal, this scope should be sent at a minimum.  This looks like a problem that will be fixed, but if fixed, will the attribute be required and therefore break my application?  Or will they opt to make the attribute optional.

Comment: I don't know about MVC4 (I'm using the PHP API) but thanks for the "openid" hint.   The documentation and it's sample do not have that and all I'd get was the invalid_scope error until I added openid